# Creating a daily Oracle partition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, partitioning, date-arithmetic

Creating oracle partition for a table for the every day.

```
ALTER TABLE TAB_123 ADD PARTITION PART_9999 VALUES LESS THAN  ('0001') TABLESPACE TS_1
```

Here I am getting error because value is decreased as 0001 as lower boundary.

Comment: Why do you not use INTERVAL partition, then the partitions will be created automatically every day.

Answer (score 3):

You can have Oracle automatically create partitions by using the `PARTITION BY RANGE`  option.

Sample DDL, assuming that the partition key is column `my_date_column` :

```
create table TAB_123 
    (  ... ) 
    partition by range(my_date_column) interval(/*numtoyminterval*/ NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'day'))
    ( partition p_first values less than (to_date('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) tablespace ts_1)
;
```

With this set up in place, Oracle will, if needed, create a partition on the fly when you insert data into the table. It is also usually a good idea to create a default partition, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

This naming convention (last digit of year plus day number) won't support holding more than ten years worth of data. Maybe you think that doesn't matter but I know databases which are well into their second decade. Be optimistic!

Also, that key is pretty much useless for querying. Most queries against partitioned tables want to get the benefit of partition elimination. But that only' works if the query uses the same value as the partition key. Developers really won't want to be casting a date to YDDD format every time they write a select on the table.

So. Use an actual date for defining the partition key and hence range. Also for naming the partition if it matters that much.

```
ALTER TABLE TAB_123 
ADD PARTITION P20200101 VALUES LESS THAN  (date '2020-01-02') TABLESPACE TS_1
/
```

Note that the range is defined by less than the next day. Otherwise the date of the partition name won't align with the date of the records in the actual partition.